# How to fix XML Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm showing the image of the desired Layout which i want to generate i'm new to android development i'm also listing my XML for this... in which i able to fix TextView and WebView but i'm not able to fix my button on left side can any one suggest me the required addtion which i have to do and where in my XML file.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >




    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtItem1"
        android:text="ITEM"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:textColor="#009966"
        android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"

        />

    <!-- WebView  -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        >

        <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


         />
    </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, Let me arrange the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Replace below Code It will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtItem1"
        android:text="ITEM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:textColor="#009966"

        />
<Button 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    />



    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- WebView  -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        >

        <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


         />
    </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Copy and Paste in your file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItem1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/txtbackground"
        android:text="ITEM"
        android:textColor="#009966" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- WebView -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too much into the details, your layout should be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
  <Button />
  <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
<WebView />
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code in your XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="TextView" />
 <WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"


     />
```